# Angular does not see variables values when using timer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

I need to call the backend function in angular's component according to the timer.
I tried 2 options:

Option N1:

```
_api: Service;

constructor(api: Service){
 this._api = api;
    if (this.timeout != null) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {   
        this.update();      
    }, 20000);
}

update()
{
this._api.GetData()….
}
```

The Result of this implementation does not run timer every N seconds, it calls update() function only once. But with this approach I can access the methods/properties of the this.api

OPTION N2:

```
_api: Service;

constructor(api: Service){
 this._api = api;
 setInterval(this.update, 2000);
}

update()
{
this._api.GetData()….
}
```

And the result is: for some reason it can't see the methods/properties of this._api.
I checked whether I can see them if I don't use setInterval and it seems that the problem is caused by setInterval.

Please advise how to arrange timer work of some method in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using `setInterval` to run the chunk every n seconds, but you need to use arrow function notation to refer to the class member variables using `this` keyword. Try the following

```js
constructor(api: Service) {
  this._api = api;
  setInterval(() => { this.update() }, 2000);    // <-- use arrow function here
}

update() {
  this._api.GetData()….
}
```

But what is the purpose of using an additional variable to refer to the injected service? You could directly refer to it.

```js
constructor(api: Service) {
  setInterval(() => { this.update() }, 2000);
}

update() {
  this.api.GetData()….
}
```

Furthermore, I presume you are making some HTTP request in the `GetData()` function. In that case, it would be better to cancel any impending requests before triggering a new one in the interval.

```
dataSubscription: any;

constructor(api: Service) {
  setInterval(() => { this.update() }, 2000);
}

update() {
  if (this.dataSubscription) {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();    // <-- unsubscribing cancels any impending requests
  }
  this.dataSubscription = this.api.GetData()….
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How about interval function provided by rxjs?](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/interval)

```js
  
class Service {
  getData() {
    return rxjs.of( Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)).fill(0).map((pr, index) => ({id: index})))
  }
}

class Component {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
    this.observable = null;
    this.ngOnInit = this.ngOnInit.bind(this);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.observable = rxjs.interval(3000)
      .pipe(rxjs.operators.mergeMap(_ => this.service.getData()));
  
  }
}

const service = new Service();
const component = new Component(service);
component.ngOnInit();
component.observable.subscribe(values => {
  console.log(values)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```